# Android LKM to Intercept system calls

Tags: android, android-emulator

Me along with my colleagues are currently working on a system that would log
the Android environment system calls. A procedure that we have researched includes the
use of an LKM in the emulator to get these calls. Question is, I have been researching
as much as I could and I have failed in finding out how this is to be done. Is there someone that can shed some light about this? Thank you!

These are the papers that I've found that both use an LKM to intercept system calls
http://www.dai-labor.de/fileadmin/Files/Publikationen/Buchdatei/Thomas_AAS_Malware2010.pdf

http://www.scribd.com/doc/86982254/Kernel-Based-Behavior-Analysis-for-Android-Malware-Detection

Again, thank you!

Comment: define *environment system calls*? Show us what you have researched.

Comment: The calls that I want to see include the read and write calls. I've edited my post to include the papers that I've seen. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for [strace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strace):

Frome the man page:

> In the simplest case strace runs the specified command until it exits. It intercepts and records the system calls which are called by a process and the signals which are received by a process.

The kernel module is [ptrace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ptrace).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I'll definitely look into this